# Set Postgres Column to equal query result

Tags: postgresql

If I had a table of products and another table of manufacturers, and I wanted that table to have a count of products, is there a way in postgres to say "this column equals the number of rows in this other table that meet this condition"?

EDIT: I mean to say that the column value will be automatically calculated. So if I have a table with a column for the number of products that are red, I want this column to consistently equal the number of rows that result from doing `select * from products where color='red';`, without having to consistently perform that query myself.

Comment: search for `group by` an `sum()`

Comment: You'll have to write a trigger to count rows matching a certain criteria from one table and plop that count in another table.

Answer (score 1):

You should not store calculated values in an operational database. If it's data warehouse, go ahead.

You can use a view to do the calculation for you.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0b744/1

You can use a [materialized view](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html) to increase performance, and refresh it with a trigger on `products` table.